# T-SQL Dates using Convert() function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am bit confusing here?

```
declare @date1 datetime = '2016-01-21 14:10:47.183'
```

I want to convert `'2016-01-21 14:10:47.183'` To `'21-01-2016'`

when I tried: `select convert(date,@date1,105)`
I am getting: `2016-01-21`

But with: `select convert(varchar(10),@date1,105)`
I am getting: `21-01-2016`

Why I am not having same results with above code?

Why should I convert to `varchar`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why is because once you put a value in a `datetime` column (or `date` or any of the other variations on date-time datatypes) in SQL Server.   SQL Server ceases to think of that date as having any particular format.   It translates it into numbers, and stores it that way internally.

So when you select a date from a date time column, SQL Server displays it in the default format that you have selected based on your environment/local settings.

If you want to display it in any other format, you have to first convert it to a string, because as far as SQL Server is concerned, dates don't have formats.   They are just numbers.   The 21st day of March is the 21st day of March, whether you write it as 3/21 or 21/3.

So when you try to convert a date to a date with a different format, SQL Server just ignores you because dates don't have formats.  However, if you want to convert that date to a string, SQL Server will be happy to help you display that string in any format you like.

Hope this helps, but sounds like some further research into how SQL Server stores dates would help your understanding.

Comment: Hi @Tab Alleman, thanks for the explanation. I got some understanding now. will dig some more how to store dates in SQL Server. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is just presentation matter and should be done in application layer. If you cannot do it in application you could use `FORMAT` (SQL Server 2012+):

```
declare @date1 datetime = '2016-01-21 14:10:47.183'

SELECT FORMAT(@date1, 'dd-mm-yyyy');
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/426312)**</kbd>

---

> Why I am not having same results with above code?

```
select convert(date,@date1,105)
-- DATETIME -> DATE
-- vs
select convert(varchar(10),@date1,105)
-- DATETIME -> VARCHAR(10) using specific style
```

If you only to skip time part use `SELECT CAST(@date1 AS DATE)` and do not bother how it is presented. It is still `DATE`.

To sum up: in SQL query use `DATE` as date, in application display it with desired format.

Comment: Hi @lad2025, thanks for the reply, but I want to know Why should I convert to `varchar`?

Comment: @user3583912 Date is date no matter how you present it. Please specify what you want to achive `DATETIME -> NVARCHAR` or `DATETIME -> DATE`?

Comment: Hi @lad2025, I want to change `DATETIME -> DATE` with different `style 105` i am having result i wanted with this `select convert(varchar(10),@date1,105)` but its not Date anymore right?

Comment: @user3583912 `select convert(varchar(10),@date1,105)` it is string, not date. If you want to use date operation on it (DATEADD, comparing and so on) you should convert it back to `DATE` or implicit conversion will occur. **To sum up: in SQL query use `DATE` as date, in application display it with desired format.**